# Deleting vector layer within buffer?

Tags: vector, buffer, intersection

I am trying to delete points from a shapefile with vector information that intersect a buffer that was created. I have tried using the intersect tool, but that only highlights the information that intersects the buffer, it doesn't highlight them in the attribute table of shapefile that I need to delete them from.

Comment: What GIS software do you have? What type of data are your buffer and points? i.e. shapefile, geodatabase feature class, GeoJSON etc..

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.